# boost bind or lambda functor that returns a constant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-lambda

Can I use boost::bind or the boost lambda library to create a functor that ignores its arguments and always returns a constant?

e.g. a functor with equivalent behaviour to:

```
int returnThree( SomeType arg ) { return 3; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Barry's comment on sehe's answer:

```
#include "boost/lambda/lambda.hpp"

...

auto returnThree = boost::lambda::constant(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use

```
boost::phoenix::val(3);
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc7c9fdfc3feb0fa)**

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace p = boost::phoenix;
using namespace p::arg_names;

int main()
{
    auto p = p::val(42);
    return p() + p(/*ignored:*/77);
}
```

Which returns `84` as the exitcode.

Comment: Even gives you up to 10 arguments, whereas `boost::lambda::constant` limits you to 3.